# How to force maven to use repositories listed in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I have a maven project which defines a list of repositories in its `pom.xml` file. However, when I run `mvn install`, maven tries to fetch the dependencies from the repositories that I've defined in my `settings.xml` file. If I delete my `settings.xml` file, then maven uses the `pom.xml` file and the compilation works.

How can I force maven to use the `pom.xml` file to fetch the dependencies without having to delete the `settings.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `settings.xml` defines a mirror, you cannot overwrite it. You can, though, run `mvn install` with the `-s` parameter to offer a different `settings.xml`.

Usually, you either define all repositories in your `settings.xml` or you use a Maven repository manager like Nexus which handles all the repositories.

Comment: I don't quite get the idea behind this. I have the settings.xml to define repositories that I use for some internal projects. This other repository which has the repositories in its `pom.xml` file, however, was not created/managed by me, and I just want to compile it locally. In this case I have to create another settings.xml file just to compile it and copy the pom.xml file content? Doesn't make much sense

Comment: My interpretation: If you have a `settings.xml` that defines a mirror, you want to avoid that projects access arbitrary repositories beyond your control. In a company, you often want to have control over the repositories used and manage those in your Nexus/Artifactory. On the other hand, you do not need to define a mirror in your settings.xml. Or you can have a different empty settings.xml for building your project.